# Two datagridviews in one windows form = not possible to save data to the second datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005, datagridview

1. I create a **winform**
2. I´m adding a **datagridview** by dragging a table from data sources
3. the result: I´ve got a winform with a datagridview and a **bindingnavigator**
4. **I´m adding a second datagridview** to the same winform by dragging another table from data sources
5. the result: same as bullet 3, but now with two datagridviews; **a second bindingnavigator is not added though, don´t ask me why!**
6. I copy the existing bindingnavigator and a adapts the copy to the second datagridview
7. I look into the .Designer.cs file, and it looks perfect regarding consistency
8. Now to the problem - even though both datagridviews have their own **BindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click** method, with code pointing out their respective bindingsources... **it´s not possible to save changes from the second datagridview to the database!**

   ```
   Anyone seen this? Any suggestions what to do?
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I solved it like this** (I thank mr/mrs/miss dretzlaff17 who started up some processes in what´s left of my doped brain)

```
  private void tableMeLikeBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     try
     {
        this.Validate();
        this.tableMeLikeBindingSource.EndEdit();

        // IMPORTANT: the following predefined generic Update command
        // does NOT work (sometimes)
        // this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.rESOURCE_DB_1DataSet);

        // instead we explicitely points out the right table adapter and updates
        // only the table of interest...
        this.tableMeLikeTableAdapter.Update(this.rESOURCE_DB_1DataSet.TableMeLike);
     }

     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        myExceptionHandler.HandleExceptions(ex);
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to set the DataSource property of the DataGridView in code through the use of a DataTable or object collection instead of using a bindingnavigator.

Comment: Thanks, you made me think in the right direction. I still use the automated stuff, though. The solution (for me) was to change UpdateAll to Update.
The thing is, UpdateAll should do it, and is "predefined" in the Save-event-handler... but some mr Gates well hidden bug makes it a bit inconsistent, especially in scenarios as stated in my Question.